# How to represent conditional sentences in OWL ontology?

Tags: owl, ontology

For example,

If weather permits, I will go hiking.

Classes:
   Weather
    Hiking

Individual:
    I

Properties:
permit
go

Answer (score 2):

You could say that if there is a weather condition at time *t* which is sunny where you are, then there will be a hiking event at the same time involving you. A example of the kind of data you may have is:

```
ex:2017-02-23  a  wc:WeatherCondition;
  t:time  "2017-02-23"^^xsd:date;
  p:place  ex:theAlps;
  wc:cloudiness  wc:sunny .
ex:i  p:located  [
  a  p:LocationAtTime;
  p:location  ex:theAlpes;
  t:time  "2017-02-23"^^xsd:date .
] .
ex:hiking2017-02-23  a  ae:HikingEvent;
  t:time  "2017-02-23"^^xsd:date;
  ae:participant  ex:i .
```

You would like a rule like:

```
?wc  a  wc:WeatherCondition;
  t:time  ?t;
  p:place  ?p;
  wc:cloudiness  wc:sunny .
ex:i  p:located  [
  a  p:LocationAtTime;
  p:location  ?p;
  t:time  ?t .
] .
```

implies:

```
[]  a  ae:HikingEvent;
  p:location  ?p;
  t:time  ?t .
```

I don't think this is doable in OWL. However, you could use a rule engine for this. Nonetheless, I am not sure that this kind of use case where the data is highly contextual and dynamic is best covered by semantic web standards.